# Which game is this die with a tornado or spiral on half its sides from?

Tags: identify-this-game-piece

Please identify the game this die (shown in the picture below) comes from.

The die has 3 blank faces, and this tornado (or spring?) design on the other 3 faces.

I don't have any other information. The die came with a different game bought at a thrift store, but does not belong.

[image: Hand holding a die, with a tornado/spring icon on its face.]

Comment: I have reasonably good familiarity with RPGs. I have never seen that symbol, and a d2 is fairly rare. It's also slightly unusual for RPGs to come with custom dice. It definitely happens (example: Fate), but most RPGs go for the broader appeal of regular gaming dice. As @from says, board games are a better bet, to the point that I recommend migrating this question over there. In contrast to RPGs, it is extremely common for board games to have custom dice.

Comment: Besides Fate (+,-, empty) and the Fantasy Flight Games, I know no game with special dice, and that is neither of those.

Comment: Can you edit in a more clear and zoomed in photo? It is kinda hard to see the exact details of the tornado.